# Net beans no reconoce el public class utilizando java

Tags: java, netbeans, apache-netbeans

Hola no entiendo porque el nombre del archivo me sale mal si se supone que es el mismo nombre que esta en el script

[image: esto es lo que pasa no se porque ni un hola mundo me deja]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

segun lo que veo en tu captura de pantalla el problema no es el nombre de la clase sino que no posees una clase principal y la clase principal es la que puedes ejecutar

Answer (score 1):

El error dice: no se pudo encontrar o cargar la clase principal, debes crear una clase con main

```
public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]